# Trouble getting and installing the latest JAI java library

Tags: java, tiff, jai

I have a couple of questions.  I'm trying to install Java JAI libraries on my Eclipse on a PC so that I can create a standalone desktop application to convert TIFF files to JPEGs.  I've searched and found links about how to do it but half are broken or very old and I'm not sure which one is the latest. Oracle site is no help and has links to download pages that don't exist.  Any help is much appreciated.

Second question I have is will this libary work on a Mac and if so how do I install it there so that my code would work on a Mac.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAI is native (written in c or c++). That means that you have to take care on which platform your application is running, is it 32bit or 64bit, etc. for each platform you need separate JAI library.
Check if java's javax.imageio.ImageIO utility supports tiff. If it does, you can simply read your tiff, then save it as jpeg. ... again i am not sure if this will work, but it is worth trying